# ¿Cómo se crea un .log de errores de macros excel?

Tags: excel, vba

mi duda es que si se pude crear un archivo.log de erres de una macro, he buscado por todos lados y no he encontrado alguien que lo haya implementado, y si, si me dan una idea de como seria

Option Explicit

```
    ' variable tipo objeto se utulizara para conectarnos
    Public obj_conexion As ADODB.Connection

    ' variable de identificacion para la BD
    Dim campo_uno, campo_dos, campo_tres, campo_cuatro, campo_cinco

    ' variable para inspeccionar el numero de registros
    Dim var_Fila, var_Final As Integer

    ' funcion con los parametros de conexion
    Function Connect(cons_instancia As String, cons_usuario As String, cons_contra As String, cons_base_datos As String) As Boolean

        'Aquí se estable la conexion
        Set obj_conexion = New ADODB.Connection
        On Error Resume Next

        With obj_conexion

            .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
                                "Password=" & cons_contra & ";" & _
                                "Persist Security Info=True;" & _
                                "User ID=" & cons_usuario & ";" & _
                                "Initial Catalog=" & cons_base_datos & ";" & _
                                "Data Source=" & cons_instancia                
            .Open
        End With

        If obj_conexion.State = 0 Then
            Connect = False
        Else
            Connect = True
        End If

    End Function

    Function Query()
        Dim var_consulta As String
        Dim var_resultado As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim var_campo As ADODB.Field 'maneja los campos de la BD

        Dim var_columna As Long 'maneja las columnas de la hoja de calculo

        Set var_resultado = New ADODB.Recordset

    'aquí busca todo los registros que haya en la hoja
    var_Final = GetUltimoR(Hoja1)

    'aquí se igualan las filas y columnas correspondientes a las variable que contrendran los datos que se encuentran en hoja de calculo y que se enviaran a la BD
    For var_Fila = 2 To var_Final
        campo_uno = Hoja1.Cells(var_Fila, 2)
        campo_dos = Hoja1.Cells(var_Fila, 3)
        campo_tres = Hoja1.Cells(var_Fila, 4)
        campo_cuatro = Hoja1.Cells(var_Fila, 5)
        campo_cinco = Hoja1.Cells(var_Fila, 6)

        var_consulta = "insert into tabla_prueba values('" & campo_uno & "','" & campo_dos & "','" & campo_tres & "','" & campo_cuatro & "','" & campo_cinco & "');"
        var_resultado.Open var_consulta, obj_conexion
    Next

        var_resultado.Open "SELECT * FROM tabla_prueba", obj_conexion

        If var_resultado.State Then
            var_columna = 1

            For Each var_campo In var_resultado.Fields
                Cells(1, var_columna) = var_campo.Name
                var_columna = var_columna + 1
            Next var_campo

            Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset var_resultado
            Set var_resultado = Nothing
        End If
    End Function

    Function Disconnect()
        obj_conexion.Close
    End Function

    Public Sub run()
        Dim var_consulta As String
        Dim var_cadena_conexion As Boolean


        var_cadena_conexion = Connect("192.168.10.12", "sa", "Password", "prueba")

        If var_cadena_conexion Then

            Call Query
            Call Disconnect
        Else

            MsgBox "No podemos Conectarnos!"
        End If
    End Sub
```

este es mi codigo, pero no se como implemento la función para el log de errores

Comment: No hay funcionalidad específica, pero usando la funcionalidad básica de I/O de archivos se puede implementar fácilmente. Te sugiero que completes tu pregunta agregando un ejemplo del código que deseas auditar y que tipo de mensajes buscas salvar en el log.

Comment: mira el codigo debe ingresar los registros a la BD, esto ya lo hice, pero no se como crear la función del  de que cuando un usuario ingrese el dato mal guarde el mensaje en el archivo de errores

Comment: Karla, mi comentario viene por el lado que tu pregunta es muy escueta, no muestras lo que has intentado ni lo que has investigado, la idea es que sea bien recibida por la comunidad y así incrementar tus chances para obtener una buena respuesta. Si no lo has hecho te sugiero que veas [ask]. Saludos..

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes el numero de error y sabes exactamente en que punto se produce, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
on error resume next
'Tu código. 
if err.number = "NumeroDeErrorQueConoces" then
    'Guardas los datos que recopilas en tu archivo de texto.
    goto error
end if
'Más codigo.
error:
```